# Como faço minha table com scroll infinito?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, table, rolamento

Tenho a seguinte situação: quero que ao chegar ao fim da table faça uma requisição Ajax e retorne mais 10 linhas na minha table. Por exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
         table {
            width: 100%;
        }

        thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }
        thead{
             background: #ccc url(https://www.devfuria.com.br/html-css/tabelas/bar.gif) repeat-x left center; 
        }
        tr:after {
            content: ' ';
            display: block;
            visibility: hidden;
            clear: both;
        }

        thead th {
            height: 30px;

            text-align: left;
        }

        tbody {
            height: 120px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        thead {
            /* fallback */
        }


        tbody td, thead th {
            width: 19.2%;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="table" class="tabela">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
<h1 class="teste">hey</h1>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(".teste").click(function() { 
    alert('hey')
 });
 $("#table").click(function() { 
    alert('table')
 });
// detecta quando chega ao fim da div
$("tbody").scroll(function() { 


        if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() == $(this).get(0).scrollHeight) {
            alert("final")
             var row = 2;
                $.ajax({

                            //envia dados para o fetch_data.php
                            url: 'teste3.php',
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {row:row},
                            success: function(response){
                                     $("tbody").html(response); 
                            }
                        });
        } 
    }); 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Faço a requisição Ajax quando o scroll chega ao final da table para o arquivo teste3.php mas quando o valor é retornado os anteriores somem, quero que a lista table só vá aumentando.

Segue o código do arquivo teste3.php:

```
<?php


$row = $_POST['row']+1;
echo "  <tr>
        <td class='filterable-cell'>heye</td>
        <td class='filterable-cell'>Escort</td>
        <td class='filterable-cell'>Blue</td>
        <td class='filterable-cell'>2000</td>
    </tr>";
```

Comment: acho que você precisa utilizar um append: https://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: vou tentar @CezarCruz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só consultar o manual e ver que o método [**.html()**](https://api.jquery.com/html/) possui duas funções: uma é **pegar** o HTML interno e outra é **substituir** o HTML interno de um elemento.

Ao fazer `$("tbody").html(response);` você está substituindo o conteúdo (HTML interno) do `tbody`, ou seja, em vez de acrescentar novas linhas, você está substituindo as linhas existentes.

No caso do scroll infinito, você deveria usar o método [**.append()**](https://api.jquery.com/append/), que **acrescenta** novo conteúdo no final do elemento, ou seja:

```
$("tbody").append(response);
```

Comment: bem isso, obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Olá, segue um exemplo com append, e scroll: auto, acredito que seja a melhor alternativa neste caso. no lugar do botão, é só colocar um "for" ou "while".
Execute aqui mesmo para testar.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("ol").append("<li>Appended item</li>");
  });
});
```

```css
<style>
div.ex1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>

<h1>The overflow Property</h1>

<h2>overflow: auto:</h2>
  <div class="ex1">
     Aqui dentro vai sua tabela!!
    <ol>
      <li>List item 1</li>
      <li>List item 2</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <button id="btn2">Novo item da tabela</button

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: usei o append e funciona, obrigada!

Comment: legal, se quiser marcar positivo a resposta então, valeu xp